# Length for starting values for nlme models in R-- how do I know?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a nonlinear mixed effect model in R.  I am doing this step by step to make it easier to find the starting values for my model.  It looks like this:

```
fit.nlme.10<-nlme(fit.beta.10, random=pdDiag(w.max ~1))

cfs <- fixef(fit.nlme.10)
fit.nlme2 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(w.max ~ trt, t.e + t.m ~ 1),
                start = c(cfs[1], rep(0,2), cfs[2:3]))

cfsT <- fixef(fit.nlme2)


fit.nlme3 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(w.max ~ ground, t.e + t.m ~ 1),
             start = c(cfs[1], rep(0,1), cfs[2:3]))

cfsG <- fixef(fit.nlme3)

fit.nlme4 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(w.max ~ trt + ground, t.e + t.m ~ 1),
                    start = c(cfsT2[1:3], cfsG2[1:2], cfs[2:3]))
```

The idea is to use the coefficients of the previous fits for starting values as the model gets more complex.  I have successfully done this before, but never completely understood it.  I often get the error message "starting values for the fixed component are not the correct length".  I spend a lot of time playing around with the lengths until I don't the error message anymore.

Can anyone explain to me how I can know what the correct length is from the beginning?

Sorry not to attach data, but to run this you would also need some lengthy custom functions.

Comment: I think that, if the function has three parameters and each is depedant on two factor of 3 levels each then you must provide three starting values. Each times the number of levels in your factor. If there is interaction you must multiply the number of levels, if not simply add the number of levels. Let me know if this works and I'll make an answer.

Comment: @Iselzer The idea didn't work for me.  I kept changing the numbers of my last model until something worked.  I have three treatments (trt) and I used two starting values and I have two locations (ground) and I used two starting values for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trick that you could use is to fit a `lm` with the same fixed terms and count the number of coefs.

```
temp<-length(coef(lm(w.max ~ trt + ground,data)))
fit.nlme4 <- update(fit.nlme.10, fixed = list(w.max ~ trt + ground, t.e + t.m ~ 1),
                start = c(cfs[1], rep(0,temp-1), cfs[2:3]))
```